# Select/Add next occurrence of current selection on Visual Studio 2013/2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

How do I select the next occurrence of the current selection in VS 2013 and VS 2015?

As a reference for what I want, in Sublime Text/Visual Studio Code, this is achieved by using CTRL+D.

Tried to google it, found similar hotkeys but not exactly what I need.

Comment: there is a way to do it. If you are not sure what to do you can always go in the Tools > Options > Keyboard.  It will have a list of all the keyboard shortcuts you can search from there and if there is no key assigned for it you can assign one.

Comment: But you will need to use an Extension like MixEdit or Multi-Edit.  By Default Visual Studio does not have a multi-cursor feature or functionality built into it. Therefore you are not finding anything in your searches. FYI MixEdit is paid about $10 U.S. multi-edit is free but doesn't have as many features.

Answer (score 1):

You can find keyboard shortcuts on Microsoft's [Keyboard shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#bkmk_text-editor-context-specific-shortcuts) page.

The shortcuts you are probably looking for are:

| Default Shortcut | Meaning | VS Command |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> | Select next matching occurrence. | Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret |
| <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> | Select all matching occurrences. | Edit.InsertCaretsatAllMatching |

Note that it is possible to change these shortcuts in the settings, so your setup may be different. The shortcuts can be found in Tools->Options->Keyboard. Then look for the VS Command in the table above. These can also be found on the Edit->Multiple Carets menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but this has been added.  On mac it's COMMAND + D

Comment: The question is for Visual Studio 2013/2015, *not* Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I know the question was for Visual Studio Community but I had the same question for visual studio code..  and this was my answer! so yeah, I forgive him :)